# SQL Join on where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

How do I join these two tables

```
select m.caseno,
sum(m.BalanceAmount) GOVT from TABLE1 m
inner join TABLE2 g on m.Code = g.Code
where g.alpha in ('a','b','c') 
group by m.caseno
```

OUTPUT 
CASE | GOVT

```
select m.caseno,
sum(m.BalanceAmount) MIF from TABLE1 m
inner join TABLE2 g on m.Code = g.Code
where g.alpha in ('d','e')
group by m.caseno
```

OUTPUT 
CASE | MIF

I want them to join in a single query
CASE | GOVT | MIF

Comment: Is Table1 & Table2 the same table in both queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case when to show as 2 columns.

```
select m.caseno,
sum(case when g.alpha in ('d','e') then m.BalanceAmount else 0 end)  MIF ,
sum(case when g.alpha in ('a','b','c') then m.BalanceAmount else 0 end)  GOVT 
from TABLE1 m
inner join TABLE2 g on m.Code = g.Code
where g.alpha in ('a','b','c','d','e')
group by m.caseno
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is also correct and much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to touch the existing queries, you can do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` with them:

```
select
  coalesce(a.caseno, b.caseno) as caseno,
  a.govt,
  b.mif
from ( -- first query
  select m.caseno,
  sum(m.BalanceAmount) GOVT from TABLE1 m
  inner join TABLE2 g on m.Code = g.Code
  where g.alpha in ('a','b','c') 
  group by m.caseno
) a
full outer join ( -- second query
  select m.caseno,
  sum(m.BalanceAmount) MIF from TABLE1 m
  inner join TABLE2 g on m.Code = g.Code
  where g.alpha in ('d','e')
  group by m.caseno
) b on a.caseno = b.caseno
```

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` is necessary -- as well as the `COALESCE()` -- to join non-matching rows that may show up in either queries.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but what join should I use if I want to know that some case does not have a value for another column

Comment: If you only want the rows present on both queries, then use a simple `JOIN` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Is this what you need?

Comment: I think what i need is the full outer join, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

you have to perform a full outer join i think. try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  select m.caseno,
    sum(m.BalanceAmount) GOVT from TABLE1 m
  inner join TABLE2 g on m.Code = g.Code
  where g.alpha in ('a','b','c') 
  group by m.caseno
) AS tab1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  select m.caseno,
    sum(m.BalanceAmount) MIF from TABLE1 m
  inner join TABLE2 g on m.Code = g.Code
  where g.alpha in ('d','e')
  group by m.caseno
) AS tab2 
  ON tab2.caseno = tab1.caseno
```